# What is the long tag for?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow

Apologies if this is not the place to ask, but I have a question about a tag on Stack Overflow.

I noticed today the tag [long](/questions/tagged/long) on a bunch of questions.  Some are using long to mean a long period of time and some are using long to mean a data type.  Can I ask, what is it supposed to mean as there is no tag wiki for it?

Comment: This seems to be a candidate for removal in many (most?) uses, and disambiguation in the rest.

Comment: [long-int] seems less ambiguous. Hell some of those questions are about long as a time frame...

Answer (score 3):

Probably, the tag should be removed altogether.
It could make sense when referring to a data type, but I am not sure in which cases it should be required to use a tag to mean the question is about a long integer. Additionally, if there is already a tag that specify the question is about an integer datatype, does [long](/questions/tagged/long) add anything?

It is wrong to use [long](/questions/tagged/long) to mean *a long period of time*: The answer doesn't change because that tag, nor are there any experts in long periods of time, on Stack Overflow.

The least that should be done is to remove the tag from questions that are not about a datatype, and edit the tag wiki to explain the tag is for a datatype found in many programming languages.
If there is a tag for which [long](/questions/tagged/long) can be a synonym, the synonym could be created. Alternatively, [long](/questions/tagged/long) can be renamed, as Robert Harvey suggest.

Comment: _Immediately goes off to master the fine art of `long period of time`_

Comment: Is that archaeology? `;)`

Comment: Man, you guys are so severe about these things.  You do realize it's expensive to burn a tag, don't you?  You have to involve the SE staff to do it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Uhh, no, [tag:archaeology] refers to humans only. :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I guess it's better to merge it with long-int, and somebody PLEASE edit the tagwiki.

Comment: I already edited the tag wiki.  Caching?

Comment: If we remove that tag why wouldn't we then remove short, int, decimal, byte, string, or arrays.

Comment: @ConradFrix: *[sees the light]*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Probably; works now. Yep, your suggestion of create-new-tag+synonym seems fine.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If the tag can be merged with another one, that is preferable. Burning the tag is probably excessive, in this case.

Comment: @ConradFrix: That's why we rename it to the less ambiguous [tag:long-int]/[tag:long-integer].

Comment: @Manishearth ..and short-int/short-integer too? Why because short integral datatypes got no reason to live

Comment: @Manishearth Well, maybe between a thousand years there will be "Computer Science Archeology." I imagine how long they could laugh reading the code we write nowadays. `;)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I see what you did there ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about we just change the name to `long-integer` and synonymize `long` to it?

Comment: Why keep it at all?  It's not something people will be experts about, it's not something people will search questions on, and won't long-integer mean different things based on what language you're in?

Comment: All good points. But changing the name is easier,  and I don't see any harm in keeping it.

Comment: probably right—might not be worth it to burninate the tag.  Is there a way to "close" a tag, where it stays, but can't be used in the future?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I thought we agreed that the long tag wasn't useful, and that deleting it would be more work than it's worth.  Preventing future use of it would make sense to me.

Comment: The `long` tag is ambiguous. That's the problem at hand.  Synonymizing it to long-integer solves the problem of its misuse.